# Python Tkinter [ can't invoke command: application has been destroyed ]

Tags: python, window, tkinter

I'm creating two functions on Python :

- one to open a new window : new_window()
- another one to create a button on it : create_buttons('text displayed')

When I launch them, new_window works well but create_button displays [can't invoke "button" command: application has been destroyed] as if my master window had been destroyed... But my window is still open !

... Do you have any idea ??

```
import Tkinter

from Tkinter import *

def new_window():

   master = Tk()

def create_buttons(display):

   new_button= Button(master, text=display)

   new_button.pack()

new_window() ### OK, CREATES A WINDOW

create_buttons('text') ### DISPLAYS FOLLOWING BUG :

create_buttons('text')

TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

/neurospin/grip/protocols/MRI/childrenDTIreading_Letarnec_2011/tools/data_mysql/<ipython console> in <module>()

/neurospin/grip/protocols/MRI/childrenDTIreading_Letarnec_2011/tools/data_mysql/<ipython console> in create_buttons(display)

/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk/Tkinter.pyc in __init__(self, master, cnf, **kw)
   2003             overrelief, state, width
   2004         """
-> 2005         Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
   2006 
   2007     def tkButtonEnter(self, *dummy):

/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk/Tkinter.pyc in __init__(self, master, widgetName, cnf, kw, extra)
   1933                 del cnf[k]
   1934         self.tk.call(
-> 1935             (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
   1936         for k, v in classes:
   1937             k.configure(self, v)

TclError: can't invoke "button" command:  application has been destroyed
```

Comment: `master` is a local variable in `new_window()`. Don't use wildcard imports (`*`) outside interactive Python console.

Answer (score 1):

As J.F.Sebastian said, you need to make the `master` variable available to the palce where the button is created. Some code doing that might look like this:

```
from Tkinter import *

def new_window():
   return Tk()

def create_buttons(master, display):
   new_button = Button(master, text=display)
   new_button.pack()

master = new_window()
create_buttons(master, 'text')
```

That is not pretty, but should be good enough to fiddle around a bit. If the code should get serious, better wrap the new window and its buttons into a class of its own.